# Can't connect to wireless Macbook pro

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro

I cannot connect wireless on the macbook pro running linux.

So Linux is pretty much useless as my router is far away and in a spot that is annoying to work in, so, I need wireless.

Any help would greatly will be well accepted.

I have a broadcom BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331]

```
*************** info trace ***************

***** uname -a *****

Linux Jesus 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:13:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

***** lsb_release *****

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

***** lspci *****

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
02:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Memory Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

***** lsusb *****

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8509 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 05ac:821d Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. IR Receiver [built-in]
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05ac:0252 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ANSI)

***** PCMCIA Card Info *****


***** iwconfig *****


***** rfkill *****

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

***** lsmod *****

b43                   378855  0 
mac80211              555198  1 b43
cfg80211              208382  2 b43,mac80211
ssb                    52834  1 b43
bcma                   35762  1 b43

***** nm-tool *****

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.6
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1



***** NetworkManager.state *****

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

***** NetworkManager.conf *****

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

***** interfaces *****

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


***** iwlist *****


***** resolv.conf *****

nameserver 127.0.0.1

***** blacklist *****

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

***** modinfo *****

filename:       /lib/modules/3.5.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     B17695451431A52A474624A
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev1Dcl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev11cl*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev10*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0F*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0D*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0C*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0B*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0A*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev09*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev07*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev06*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev05*
depends:        ssb,mac80211,bcma,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.5.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.5.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     657007C65032F6BDD9475AB
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000432Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004329sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004328sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004325sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004324sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8D6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004322sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004321sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004320sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004319sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014A4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004315sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004312sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004311sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004307sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004306sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004301sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.5.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

filename:       /lib/modules/3.5.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     2C92CCB735C6654CB7E788B
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004727sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004357sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004353sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004331sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00000576sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.5.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 


***** udev rules *****

# PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0 (tg3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

***** dmesg *****

[    8.354410] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.354448] bcma: Found chip with id 0x4331, rev 0x02 and package 0x09
[    8.354477] bcma: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x25, class 0x0)
[    8.354502] bcma: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x1D, class 0x0)
[    8.354559] bcma: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x13, class 0x0)
[    8.418258] bcma: Bus registered
[    9.560627] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4331 WLAN found (core revision 29)
[    9.562873] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode29_mimo.fw" not found
[    9.562875] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode29_mimo.fw" not found
[    9.562876] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.

****************** done ******************
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: I gave what my wireless chip is!

Comment: If you could add `/var/log/udev` and `/var/log/dmesg` it would be great help.

Comment: Please look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166944 for all the information needed :)

Comment: i don't know what I am doing honestly. I just installed linux today. I don't know what /var/log/udev and the like are.

Comment: The information I posed there is too long for the comment by 8000 characters.

Comment: Added it my friend.

Answer (score 3):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and tell us if the wireless is working now.

Comment: @Jesus By not selecting this as the answer, you're making an inconvenience for everyone. Please press the check mark next to this post.

Answer (score 0):

1.) First update apt-get:

```
apt-get update
```

2.) Then update Linux Headers (this code will determine "your" systems necessary headers) and install Broadcom DKMS:

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

3.) Remove any possible active drivers for the Broadcom WiFi adapter:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

4.) Activate the wl driver for the Broadcom WiFi adapter:

```
modprobe wl
```

5.) Always best to reboot your system after things like this:

```
reboot
```