# 2008 MacBook WiFi doesn't work with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, 13.04, macbook, macosx

I had Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard installed on my MacBook. It was getting slow, so I backed it up and installed Ubuntu 13.04. But now my WiFi doesn't work.

Comment: Well I have searched the internet and haven't really found anything.

Comment: Search "ubuntu mac wifi not working," you should get tons.

Comment: I did, there is nothing for macbooks since apple discontinued them. Now there are only macbook pros

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331465/cant-connect-to-wireless-macbook-pro/331479#comment422972_331479) should do it.

Comment: When installing ubuntu, have you tried selecting the last option on the list to install third-party software? when you do that, you should be able to use such features in the boot disk and when ubuntu is installed to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a 2008 Macbook Core 2 duo, aluminum
running Ubuntu 13.04

This answer here worked for me:

[Running Ubuntu 12.04 on Mac](http://tech-devnet.blogspot.com/2012/05/running-ubuntu-1204-on-mac.html)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpodroid/mactel
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
sudo reboot
```